# cross compiling an application in c++ on yocto which has scons build system

Tags: cross-compiling, linker-errors, scons, yocto-recipe, automotive-grade-linux

I am trying to compile an application/project which is written in c/c++ and has scons build system on yocto. I wrote a recipe file that leverages scons already written code. I exported a few environment variables (like libpath, cppflags, cpppath etc) from yocto side to scons (like sysroot path for providing standard header files and libraries). This works fine till compilation but as soon as the linking starts, it fails with error:-

```
| x86_64-agl-linux-g++ -o variant_debug/BaseTools/libCXLBaseTools.so -shared 
variant_debug/BaseTools/src/gtIAllocationFailureObserver.os
variant_debug/BaseTools/src/gtIAssertionFailureHandler.os
variant_debug/BaseTools/src/gtErrorString.os
variant_debug/BaseTools/src/gtList.os
variant_debug/BaseTools/src/gtSingeltonsDelete.os
variant_debug/BaseTools/src/gtStringTokenizer.os
-L/home/agl-embedded/agl_native/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/tools/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib
-L/home/agl-embedded/agl_native/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/tools/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-agl-linux/11.4.0
-L/home/agl-embedded/agl_native/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/tools/Tools/Profiler/Output_x86_64/debug/bin
| /home/agl-embedded/agl_native/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/tools/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-agl-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-agl-linux/gcc/x86_64-agl-linux/11.4.0/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
| /home/agl-embedded/agl_native/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/tools/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-agl-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-agl-linux/gcc/x86_64-agl-linux/11.4.0/ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
| /home/agl-embedded/agl_native/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/tools/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-agl-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-agl-linux/gcc/x86_64-agl-linux/11.4.0/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libmvec.so.1: No such file or directory
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| scons: *** [variant_debug/BaseTools/libCXLBaseTools.so] Error 1
| scons: building terminated because of errors.
| *** ERROR during the build of this subcomponent ***
```

### Recipe file:-

DESCRIPTION = "Build Project"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://project.tar.gz"
inherit scons

```bash
do_compile:prepend() {
    export SYSROOT="${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}"
    export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}"
    export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
}

do_compile() {
    ~/agl_native/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/tools/Tools/Profiler/Build/Linux/./build.sh dbg
}
```

Could somebody help me understand what am I missing and why am I getting this error and any possible solution? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: I am fairly new to Yocto. Please let me know if you need more information.

I added Path which has missing c runtime libraries in the "LIBPATH".
My code to add the above path in SConstruct:-

```py
sysroot_path = os.environ.get('SYSROOT', '')
env.Append(CPPPATH=[
    sysroot_path + '/usr/include',
    sysroot_path + '/usr/include/c++/11.4.0',
    sysroot_path + '/usr/include/c++/11.4.0/x86_64-agl-linux',
    ])

env.Append(LIBPATH=[
    sysroot_path + '/usr/lib',
    sysroot_path + '/usr/lib/x86_64-agl-linux/11.4.0',
    ])
```

Comment: It's hard to tell much, as you've apparently edited the error message.  If this bit is accurate, it's not pointing to the right place: `-L/path/to/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/ x86_64-agl-linux/11.4.0` because of the space, but was that space added by your editing?

Comment: This also looks odd. `x86_64-agl-linux-g++ -o path/to/.so -shared path/to/.os path/to/.os path/to/.os path/to/.os path/to/.os`. Am I safe in assuming you've sanitized your file names and paths? If so that could hamper being able to help you. Which package are you trying to build and where is it available for download?

Comment: @MatsWichmann i have edited the question, could you please take a look?

Comment: It cannot find 3 files: `crti.o`, `crtbeginS.o` and `/usr/lib/libmvec.so.1`. Did you check if those files are present in your system?

Comment: @PiotrSiupa these files are present in the path [sysroot_path + '/usr/lib'] which i have included in the 'LIBPATH' environment variable.

Comment: What I would do is to write a correct linker command and after making sure it works, compare it to the command produced by SCons. They will either the same which could mean the some environment variables or something like that is needed to be set correctly. Or they will be different and we can figure out how to make them the same.

Comment: One particularly odd item is the failure on `/usr/lib/libmvec.so.1` which I don't see mentioned in the link at all (the crt files are "implied" and normal), and which has an absolute path, which is almost certainly going to be wrong for a cross-build.  Seems like there may be something missing from the above still.  Are you by any chance picking up a linker script, they sometimes have embedded absolute paths.